# ASP.NET MVC 5.2 Monodevelop. Form post with parameters not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, monodevelop

I'm trying to get this to work on monodevelop ASP.NET MVC 5.2 :

**View:** Login.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <table>

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="UserName" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="password" name="Password" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" /></td></tr>

    </table>

}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string test) // <--- Not happy about this. 
{
  return View (); 
}
```

I get the following error if I add parameter string test. Or any parameter really :

***System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'System.Web.UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.***

Some posts suggest that 'System.Web.UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase' is not implemented in mono and a year later it seems to still be the case.

Hope I'm doing something wrong and that I don't have to install MVC4 (not finding it in nuget anyway on monodev).

Comment: There's no field with the name test at your form!

Comment: I've added one. No luck :(

Comment: I did manage to get it to work in mono MVC 4 to some degree. But due to other things that was broken I decided to go with the `less` broken MVC 5 on monodevelop.

Comment: This example works beautifully in visual studio. I think I should finish the project in that.